# Is there a better way to do this using generics?

Tags: c#, generics

Here is my code. I'm new to generics so just wondering if there is a better way of doing what I have done.

```
public interface IMessageHandler<T>  where T : IMessage
{
    void Handle(T message);
}

public class MessageANotificationHandler : IMessageHandler<MessageA>
{
    public void Handle(MessageA message)
    {
        // do something;
    }

}
```

Now I want my application to receive messages which all implement IMessage but figure out automatically which handler to use for a particular message. I have done the following but have a feeling there has to a better way

```
public class MessageHandlerFactory
{
    public Type GetMessageHandlerType(IMessage message)
    {
        if (message.GetType() == typeof(MessageA))
            return typeof(MessageANotificationHandler);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in my application, I use reflection to create an instance of the type returned by the factory and invoke the Handle method.

Please help if you know any way of making this code better.

Thanks

Comment: Why not flip the dependencies and make each IMessage type be responsible for calling its own message handler? That way runtime type selection can be handled as part of the vtable call.

Comment: Why can't you just have your methods that call Handle accept an IMessage interface? That way you won't need a factory to look it up.. it will accept anything that implements IMessage..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead nailed it. That's the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the factory and the `IMessageHandler` interface.. they aren't needed.

I would add the `Handle` method to the `IMessage` interface, that way instead of this:

```
public void HandleMessageFor(IMessage msg) {
    Type t = new MessageHandlerFactory().GetMessageHandlerType(msg);
    // Activator.CreateInstance.. etc etc..
}
```

You can simply have..

```
public void HandleMessageFor(IMessage msg) {
    msg.Handle();
}
```

Comment: I need to distribute concrete implementations of IMessage to my clients and don't want to distribute the handling logic to the clients. The message handling logic should live on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `IMessage` an abstract base class instead, and have a method:

```
public abstract class MessageBase {
    public abstract IMessageHandler GetHandler();
}
```

This would require `IMessageHandler` to be non-generic then.